# For loop, trigger next / previous item from the outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I just got my hands on Python (Flask) for the first time. I'm trying to build a simple API which will act as a remote playlist with **Play / Pause / Stop  / Prev / Next features.**

I've managed to build the first two features (Play / Stop), how ever I need some ideas for (Prev / Next). Bare in mind that at the end of every iteration, I have a sleep event. I'm using multithreading (Auto enabled by Flask) to be able to call **stop()** while **play()** is running.

```
playing = 0


@app.route('/play', methods=['POST'])
def play():
    mediaFiles = request.json
    global playing
    playing = 1
    while playing == 1:
        for file in mediaFiles['mediaFiles']:
            if playing == 0:
                break
            print(file['path'])
            time.sleep(5)
    return 'Played'


@app.route('/stop')
def stop():
    global playing
    playing = 0
    return 'Stopped...'
```

I've tried creating the global 'currentIndex' variable which would keep track of the last played index in an array, and then use [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to rotate the array and start from the position where it was paused. This could work, but then again I still have Prev / Next features left

I believe that there's a better way than using while and for to handle this, because from what I see it might not even be possible to use this approach and have (Prev / Next) features.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to keep the current index for the file. But Just a hint but it could be more or less:

```
playing = 0

current_index = 0


@app.route('/play', methods=['POST'])
def play():
    mediaFiles = request.json
    global playing
    playing = 1
    while playing == 1:
        for current_index, file in enumerate(mediaFiles['mediaFiles'][current_index:], current_index):
            if playing == 0:
                break
            print(file['path'])
            time.sleep(5)
        current_index = 0            # loop back to 0 after last file
    return 'Played'
```

Prev/Next features would just have to increase/decrease `current_index`. The hard part is that you will have to build a synchronized iterator to prevent race conditions if you try to update current_index from different threads.

For example you could use:

```
class syncenumerate:
    def __init__(self, lock, iterable, start=0):
        self.lock = lock
        self.iter = enumerate(iterable, start)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            ret = next(self.iter)
        finally:
            self.lock.release()    # ensure that the lock is released at StopIteration
        return ret
```

You get thread safe synchronization easily:

```
playing=0
lck = threading.Lock()
current_changed = 0
...
    while playing == 1:
        for current_index, file in syncenumerate(lck, mediaFiles['mediaFiles']
                [current_index:], current_index):
            if current_changed = 1:    # restart enumeration is current was changed
                lck.acquire()
                current_changed = 0
                lck.release()
                break
            if playing == 0:
                ...
```

And change for example in Next:

```
lck.acquire()
current_index += 1
if current_index >= max: current_index = 0
current_changed = 1
lck.release()
```

Comment: I ended up using threading.Condition() and it's wait() and notify() functions. That way for Next, I only had to call notify(), and for previous I've used a current_index tracker. Didn't use syncenumerate. Thanks though!